# Calculating area of intersection

Tags: calculus

I am to calculate the area of the area between the intersection of these two functions:

$x-y=7$ and $x=2y^2-y+3$

I could do this easily if the $y$ variable wasn't squared!

I would simply set the functions on the form: $y = f(x)$ and then set $f(x) = 0$ and set the equations equal to find their point of intersection and then take the integral with the lower and upper limit of the intersections...But what do I do if I have a $y^2$? Thank you.

Comment: You can also set them in the form $x=f(y)$.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this, but you can interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$, getting $y-x=7$ and $y=2x^2-x+3$. That does not change the area, but may make the problem feel more familiar. In either version, draw a reasonably good picture.

Comment: Okay I get $x=-1$ and $x=2$...But these are the y-points of intersection. Can I just plug in these values into the equations to get the x values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, determine the intersection points of the curves via substitution:
$$\begin{aligned}
(2y^2 - y + 3) - y &= 7\\
2y^2 - 2y + 3 &= 7\\
2y^2 - 2y - 4 &= 0\\
2(y^2 - y - 2) &= 0\\
2(y - 2)(y + 1) &= 0\\
y &= -1,2
\end{aligned}$$
According to the [graphs of the given expressions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%E2%88%92y=7%20and%20x=2y%5E2%E2%88%92y%2b3), we construct the following integral:

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Area} &= \int_{-1}^2 (\text{Right}(y) - \text{Left}(y))\,dy\\
&= \int_{-1}^2 \left((y + 7) - (2y^2 - y + 3)\right)\,dy
\end{aligned}$$

One constructs such integral with $y$ bounds via determining the rightmost and leftmost equations *within* the points of intersection.  Here, $\text{Right}(y) = y + 7$.  Solve for $x$ for $x - y = 7$ whose curve is rightmost in the $xy$-plane within the points of intersections.  Then, $\text{Left}(y) = 2y^2 - y + 3$ whose curve is the leftmost in $xy$-plane within the points of intersections.

**Note**: Also, as one user mentions, you can interchange $x$ and $y$ variables and then, determine the area.  Instead of having to determine the rightmost and leftmost curves within the bounds of intersections, one assigns such equations by the upper and lower curves.   Since the roles of $x$ and $y$ are interchanges, we need to integrate the difference of such equations with $x$ bounds.  For the setup I constructed, for such a case, we have

$$\text{Area} = \int_{-1}^2 (\text{Upper}(x) - \text{Lower}(x))\,dx = \int_{-1}^2 \left((x + 7) - (2x^2 - x + 3)\right)\,dx$$

which gives the same value as the integral first constructed.  Compare the [graphs of these equations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%E2%88%92x=7%20and%20y=2x%5E2%E2%88%92x%2b3) to the graphs of the original expressions.  The area between the intersection of the equations does not change.

Other than that, in case you want to know the answer to the problem, hover the cursor over the shaded box. :D

> The answer is $9$, which is simply found by computation.  Simplify the equation and perform the integration.  Finally, use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  Tada!

Comment: Thank you. How did you realize which was the left and which was the right value since you are doing the area with respect to y?

Comment: I didn't change $y$ to $x$.  I used the $y$-coordinates of the points of intersections in the integral.  For such case, we need to determine the rightmost and leftmost equations of the curves based on the graphs I already posted.  Adding to what I said for this comment, we geometrically determine the rightmost and leftmost curves within the intersection bounds.  Using the link to the curves of the equations I posted for my answer, what do you know about those curves?  Which is the rightmost and which is the leftmost?

Comment: I'm doing the integration and I seem to get the answer $24$ which is the same answer as I get when I integrate without the brackets around $x+y$ and $2y^2-y+3$ but the answer should be 9. How do I integrate when you split it up like that? I just tried to do $\int y+7 \ dy - \int 2y^2-y+3 \ dy$

Comment: nvm got it, must be some algebra error

Comment: shouldn't I do like the absolute value as to not get a minus value on below x=0?

Comment: There is no need for absolute value as long as the conventions of the integral setup are correct.  You can set the absolute value of the difference of equations for any case if you want to determine the total area.